# Function not accepting transfer parameters in python

Tags: function, object

I'm new to python and I'm currently trying to develop a simple program with a database connection in python. Currently, I'm trying to create a function that creates a connection to my database, asks if a specific user is in this database and return a boolean. However, my function needs two transfer parameters to work: the user and the password which are coming from the main program. However, every time I come and try to run this function I get the following error:

> TypeError: checkLogin() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Here is the code of my connection class:

```
from mysql.connector import *

class connection:

    def __init__(self, user, password, host, database):
        self.user = user
        self.password = password
        self.host = host
        self.database = database

    def writeToDB(query):
        '''Schreibt eine query auf die Datenbank'''
        conn = connect(object.user,object.password,object.host,object.database)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        
        cursor.execute(query)
        conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
    
    def checkLogin(myuser, mypassword):
        '''Fragt Login-Daten innerhalb einer Datenbank ab und liefert ein boolean zurück'''
        conn = connect(object.user,object.password,object.host,object.database)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Benutzer WHERE Benutzername like '{myuser}' AND Passwort like '{mypassword}'")
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
        if result:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

And here the part of my main class where I'm trying to call the function over the object instance newConnection:

```
def button_action():
    name = benutzername.get()
    passcode = passwort.get()
    bAllowed = newConnection.checkLogin(name, passcode)
```

I've tried several thing to fix the issue, however none of them had an effect on the error. The only thing that worked for me is transferring the function to my main program. However, this questions the object-oriented approach. I just can't see why it's not accepting the transfer parameters. Hope you can help!

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering is due to the fact that instance methods in a class need to take the instance itself (self) as their first argument. In your connection class, both writeToDB and checkLogin methods are missing self as their first parameter.

So, you can update your method to:

```
...
def writeToDB(self, query):
        '''Schreibt eine query auf die Datenbank'''
        conn = connect(user=self.user, password=self.password, host=self.host, database=self.database)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
.....


def checkLogin(self, myuser, mypassword):
        '''Fragt Login-Daten innerhalb einer Datenbank ab und liefert ein boolean zurück'''
        conn = connect(user=self.user, password=self.password, host=self.host, database=self.database)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
....
```

Supporting Articles:

[Article 1](https://www.pythonmorsels.com/what-is-self/#:%7E:text=self%20is%20the%20first%20argument%20of%20every%20method%20in%20Python&text=When%20you%20define%20a%20class%20in%20Python%2C%20every%20method%20that,that%20you%27re%20working%20with.)

[Article 2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/self-in-python-class/)

Comment: Thank you, error resolved and my program is working!